# wss - list's custom editform lost the functionality of attach file

Tags: wss-3.0

I have a added a Custom list form in editform.aspx page of sharepoint list, but by doing that the attach file button on the custom form is not working ?

Need help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any errors that come along with it> When you did the custom list form did you delete the list web part (shouldnt delete it)? If not make sure it is closed and hidden. There is also a hot fix depending on your service pack level. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953271

Comment: I have tried by hidden and close way but it didnt work. Let me check the hot fix.